# How to use different PHP-FPM pools based on directory with different roots in Nginx

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm

I'm trying to migrate some websites from an older server running Apache and mod_php, to a new server with Nginx and PHP 7 using PHP-FPM. Both sites run a PHP shopping cart in the root of the domain, and a wordpress blog running in the sub folder /news. At the moment on the old servers the word press blog is in a folder called news in the web root (thus mixed in with the shopping carts files) on the new server I'd like to split them out so that each application live in its own separate folder such that:

Files in /home/www/sitename/cart/htdocs are available at https://www.site.tld/

and

Files in /home/www/sitename/wordpress/htdocs are available at https://www.site.tld/news/

I'd also like to be able to use different PHP-FPM pools for security and if needs be to allow me to run either of the apps with a PHP 5 pool until it can be updated to run on PHP 7.

I've got close but it keeps trying to load /news/test.php from  /home/www/sitename/wordpress/htdocs//news/test.php
instead of /home/www/manicpanic/wordpress/htdocs/test.php.

Config:

```
server {
    listen iphere:443 ssl http2;

    #ssl conf

    root /home/www/sitename/cart/htdocs;    
    server_name site.tld www.site.tld;

    rewrite ^(.*)\.v[\d]+\.(css|js|png)$ $1.$2;

    location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
        expires 30d;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    location / {
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /news {
        alias /home/www/sitename/wordpress/htdocs;
        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm-wordpress.sock;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
                fastcgi_param APPLICATION_ENV production;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE default_charset=ISO-8859-1;
            }

    }

    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm-cart.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param APPLICATION_ENV production;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE default_charset=ISO-8859-1;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regular expression `location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$)` will take precedence over the prefix `location /news`, **unless** you use the `^~` modifier. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for more.

```
location ^~ /news {
    alias /home/www/sitename/wordpress/htdocs;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        ...
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        ...
    }
}
```

Also, you cannot use `$document_root$fastcgi_script_name` in conjunction with `alias` as it creates the wrong pathname. Use `$request_filename` instead.

Always `include fastcgi_params;` *before* using specific `fastcgi_param` directives, otherwise the specific settings may be silently overwritten.

Comment: Just tested that, still adding the /news/ to the file path /home/www/sitename/wordpress/htdocs/news/test.php

Comment: Did you remove the old value for `SCRIPT_FILENAME`?

Comment: Ahh never mind, seems while testing I had switched alias to root, just switched it back with your changes still in place it it works fine thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There's a super nice tutorial (though you probably can skip setting different ports):
https://pehapkari.cz/blog/2017/03/27/multiple-php-versions-the-easy-way/

#### PHP70

```
server {
    listen 8870 default_server;
    listen [::]:8870 default_server;
    server_name _;
    root /var/www/site-with-php7.0;
    index index.php;
    location / {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock; # adjust for the listen setting discussed above
    }
}
```

#### PHP56

```
server {
    listen 8856 default_server;
    listen [::]:8856 default_server;
    server_name _;
    root /var/www/site-with-php5.6;
    index index.php;
    location / {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock; # adjust for the listen setting discussed above
    }
}
```